# IF statement returning false with no data

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I am working on an elongated IF statement that produces different outputs depending on the start of a part number e.g. `3XXXXXXX = Software`, `4XXXXXXX = Hardware`.

The problem I am having is that the formula outputs `FALSE` when a part number is yet to be given to the row.

```
=IF(B2>0,IF(LEFT(D2,1)="1","Assembly",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="2","Sub-Assembly",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="3","Software",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="4","Hardware",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="5","Chemical",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="6","Spare",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="7","Spare",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="8","Document",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="9","Misc",""))))))))))
```

Please let me know if you can spot where I am going wrong!

Comment: If you want output as `BLANK` cell when part number is empty then change `""))))))))))` to `""))))))))),"")`

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something simple but I couldn't see it. Solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not putting any value for the first big condition (if B2 is not > 0)

Try this instead:

```
=IF(B2>0,IF(LEFT(D2,1)="1","Assembly",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="2","Sub-Assembly",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="3","Software",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="4","Hardware",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="5","Chemical",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="6","Spare",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="7","Spare",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="8","Document",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="9","Misc",""))))))))),"")
```

Answer (score 3):

You have at least two other options, both of them providing you better maintainable code.

If you use Excel 2016 or higher, there is the [`SWITCH`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SWITCH-function-47ab33c0-28ce-4530-8a45-d532ec4aa25e) function. Your formula will then look much more readable:

```
=IF(B2>0,SWITCH(LEFT(D2,1),"1","Assembly","2","Sub-Assembly","3","Software","4","Hardware","5","Chemical","6","Spare","7","Spare","8","Document","9","Misc",""))
```

Even in earlier Excel versions, you may use a lookup table, which provides you much higher versatility. Create a table of your categories, you may place them in a separate sheet `Categories`:

[image]

Use [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) function together with [`IFERROR`](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/IFERROR-function-C526FD07-CAEB-47B8-8BB6-63F3E417F611) to provide the default value when not found:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(D2,1),Categories!$A$1:$B$9,2,FALSE),"")
```

Comment: Appreciate the last suggestion with a dedicated range. For the `SWITCH` one, I find `CHOOSE` even simpler (as in my answer). Definitely agree on rejecting the nested-IF solution.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! I never knew the switch function existed and will make use of it. The only issue with using a vlookup is that the part number is generated automatically in a different workbook which could potentially complicate matters.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your formula like this:

```
=IF(B2<=0,"",CHOOSE(LEFT(D2,1),"Assembly","Sub-Assembly","Software","Hardware",
  "Chemical","Spare","Spare","Document","Misc"))
```

Comment: Thanks! Both the choose and switch functions are new to me. They look much cleaner and will get used often.

Comment: CHOOSE - Advantage: available even in older versions of Excel, less code.
Disadvantage: the discriminant must be only numeric, starting from 1 and continuously going up (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...).

Comment: @HonzaZidek it is exactly the case in this question, so `CHOOSE` was precisely designed for these cases, it's not a "drawback" :)

Comment: @A.S.H I am aware of it and I agree - however I am always trying to keep the answers as useful and explanatory as possible for others - a lot of people carry on the "cargo cult programming" and copy and paste parts of the code from SO without understanding. Hence I think that - even if your answer is correct in the OP's case - it should be made more explanatory and educational.

Comment: @HonzaZidek What takes priority? answering the OP's question or educating the third parties? I think the priority is for the OP - and those who read / use it later can benefit by working out how it works but that is my opinion... :)  Oh and I like both answers, especially switch which I will be looking into...

Comment: @SolarMike I always put as much explanations as possible in my answers, but sometimes code speaks for itself, and all what the reader needs is to consult the documentation of the used function. I also "appreciated" both answers btw ;)